# Condition Overlaps in Typescript

Tags: typescript, if-statement, types, conditional-statements, overlap

Lets say I have some simple logic like this:

```
let bool = false

const seven = 7
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    
arr.forEach(element => {
    if (element === seven) {
        bool = true
    }
});
```

Now I wan't to call a function if "bool" has been set to true:

```
if (bool === true){
    doSomething()
}
```

Typescript gives an error in this case:

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'false' and 'true' have no overlap.
```

Typescript complains even though logically I know that bool will be true by the time the condition block is triggered. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know that the Typescript compiler would complain on something like this, but again it's a strange way to have such a condition statement since:

```
if (bool === true)
```

is the same as:

```
if (bool)
```

But yeah you can either:

1. Write the condition in a normal way: `if (bool) { ... }` (highly recommended)
2. Force the type to be boolean: `if((bool as boolean) === true ) { ... }` (it works but please don't do this)

Comment: "Please be normal" haha. Okay, fair enough, so in typescript you either write bool, or  !bool. Got it, thanks.